# Encountering a System.IndexOutOfRangeException: when trying to display data from two tables in a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, forms

I am writing a form application. User inputs his name, email, address etc into text boxes as if he was ordering a package. If the user has already made an order once I want to make it possible for the user to enter his email into the text box and based on his email fill out all the other personal information needed for the package.

The trouble I am having is that his data is in two different tables. The data which is in customer table (his first and last name) I have successfully retrieved, but the data in the table address I don't know how to get.

Here is the code:

````
{
        try
        {
            var connection = getConnection();

            var command = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = connection,
                CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Email = @Email"
            };

            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", mailBox.Text);

            connection.Open();

            reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                fnameBox.Text = reader["fname"].ToString();
                lnameBox.Text = reader["lname"].ToString();

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM address WHERE customerID= "+ reader["customerID"].ToString();

                stateBox.Text = reader["state"].ToString();  //part where the error happens
                cityBox.Text = reader["city"].ToString();
                addressBox.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
                zipBox.Text = reader["zip"].ToString();

                int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("E-mail entered doesn't exist");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
} ```
````

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Also, why do you properly parametrise your first statement, and then inject in the second? You clearly are aware of parametrisation, so why do you create such a security hole in your second query?

Comment: @Larnu I already got the suggestion to read that article and I did but unfortunately i didn't know about the issues wit AddWithValue() when I started building the app and now I don't have enough time to finish it for my deadline.  It's a school project so the application doesn't have to be perfect. And honestly i really don't know what parametrisation is I just found a bunch of code online and sort of wrtoe my code based on that code and on code that my professor  gave me lol.

Comment: Can you not run just 1 query at the start that is a SQL join of two tables? select c.fname, c.lname, a..state, a.city, a.address from customer c JOIN address a c.id = a.customerId or similar.

Comment: @DaneBalia I think that this might be the best way to go about fixing it. I tried making a SQL join something like this                                                                                                     
`select c.fname,c.lname,c.Email,
a.state,a.city,a.street,
a.zip 
from customer c 
inner join address a 
on c.customerID = a.customerID
where c.Email = 'mail@mail'`     And now it's telling me it can't find the required email I tried both with and without the ' '

Comment: @LukaPrcic break down your problems. First, remove the where clause and try see if all the data is there and the email. If the email is not listed there is a disconnect between the two tables (maybe customerID don't map etc).

Answer (score 1):

1. Look into using something like EF in future, will clean such things up, but appreciate this is probably not feasible for what you're doing here.
2. You should get related data from multiple tables via SQL Joins (look into LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN)
3. Your problem is caused by the result set not having a `state` field, which in turn is caused by your not actually executing your `SELECT * FROM address` query - you are setting the command text but doing nothing further.  You need to create another `DataReader` for the second query and read *those* results.

Overall there's a lot of stuff to improve, but you're clearly at an early state in learning this so that's fine for now....

Comment: I've tried making a second DataReader but then it gave me an error where it said that it wasn't close or initialized lol . But I do think that the inner join in the CommandText is the way to go and another reader aswell. Thanks for the comment and trying to help if you have any other idea which might work I'll try iy out .

Comment: you would probably need a new `SqlCommand` object too, though been a while since I've done this stuff.  When using a database you should always try to do all filtering/Searching (WHERE) getting related data (JOINS) and aggregation (e.g. SUM / COUNT / AVG of all orders made by bob smith) in the database if possible;  it's what modern SQL databases are designed for so they are good at it.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't finish to read the first result and after this trying to get the second one

```
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", mailBox.Text);
           
            var customerID=0;
            var success=false;

            connection.Open();

            var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
              
            if (reader1.Read())
            {
               sucess=true;
                fnameBox.Text = reader1["fname"].ToString();
                lnameBox.Text = reader1["lname"].ToString();
                customerID=  Convert.ToInt32( reader1["customerID"].ToString());
            reader1.Close();
            }

      if( sucess)
       { 
              command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM address WHERE customerID = @CustomerID";
             command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerID);
            var reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();

            sucess=false;
            if (reader2.Read())
            {
                sucess=true;    
                stateBox.Text = reader2["state"].ToString();  
                cityBox.Text = reader2["city"].ToString();
                addressBox.Text = reader2["address"].ToString();
                zipBox.Text = reader2["zip"].ToString();
               reader2.Close();
             }
            if (success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" address select Error");
                }
      }
       else
      {
                MessageBox.Show("E-mail entered doesn't exist");
      }
                connection.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but the code you sent doesn't work i still get the same result even with your code. Only the fist name and last name of the customer get filled in the rest of the data doesn't.

Comment: @LukaPrcic I added reader.Close to my code. If it is still not working,then check you command parameters values using debugger.